# python3 audio signal processing

Tags: audio, module, python-3.x, signal-processing

A project I am working on for one of my classes is to build a simple GUI sound editor for kids using python3 (using python3 is a strict project requirement). I don't want this editor to be as complex as something like audacity but I would like to have some fun built in effects similar to the sound editor on the nintendo ds http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Nintendo_DSi_Sound.

I have been researching modules that are compatible with python3 that will help with the audio signal processing since I am very inexperienced in this area but I am running into trouble finding something that will work with python3. I found this great list of music modules for python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic but everything that seems to have the functionality I think I want such as pyo and snack, does not have python3 compatibility.

I think at this point my best option is to use NumPy and SciPy for the signal processing but I was wondering if anyone had any better suggestions or advice? Or is using NumPy and SciPy an ideal choice if I can become familiar with them?

Comment: You can try porting those modules to Python3. If you are lucky, it can turn out to be trivial. [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy/SciPy can process audio signals, but it doesn't feel "native" as you have to write lots of interface code to play the resulting data as sound or write the in some standard format (like .wav).

I'd suggest porting those modules ; it's often very easy and straightforward and a good Python exercis.